# Counting the values in one column after another column fulfills a criteria

Tags: python, pandas, csv, for-loop

so i have a CSV file with a date column and a positive sentiment column. if the positive sentiment column is positive, the column will show a 1. If not it will show a 0.

I need to be able to input a date, and for rows where the dates in the csv are later than the inputted date, i need to count the total positive score from the positive sentiment column.

So far i have managed to come up with this

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('rt_Article2.csv')
csv_date = pd.to_datetime(data["Date"])
positive_news= (data['Positive'])
user_date= datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 1, 00, 00)
user_score = 4


neg= 0
pos= 0
count=0

for i in csv_date:
     if i > user_date:
        count +=1
        for N in positive_news:
             if N == 1:
                pos +=1
        break

print (pos)
```

However, when i print(pos) it just counts everything in the positive column, regardless if it fulfils the date criteria or not.

I just started coding a month ago so i'm sorry if the code is messy.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

```
Date                Positive
April 2, 2018       0
April 1, 2018       1
April 1, 2018       0
March 31, 2018      0
```

Update: i also have to return the date for the first positive score and the last positive score once it reaches the user_score which in this case is 4. In other words, i need to get the date when the score is one, and the date when the score reaches 4.

Comment: Do you have some sample data to share?

Comment: Can you post the sample of the `CSV` file also?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to the loop, with pandas, looping almost always unnecceary:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':np.random.choice(pd.date_range('2017-09-01','2017-09-30'),500),'positive':np.random.choice([0,1],500)})

df.loc[df['date'] == '2017-09-15','positive'].sum()
```

Output:

```
13
```

Comment: does this method work if i have to return the date for the first positive score and the last positive score once it reaches the user_score which in this case is 4. In order words,  i need to get the date when the score is one, and the date when the score reaches 4.